# how to prevent when we call url from other backed it should not append my current url in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

how to prevent when we call URL from other backed it should not append my current URL in Laravel,

for example, in the link column, I have store www.google.com and when I am calling this URL in Laravel new it is appending my current URL to it

give me a solution to prevent that means when I will call that link it should open in a new tab independently without appending any other URL to it.

[image]

in image you can see i have added url but when i am clicking on same it appends my current website url also,

example www.abc.com/www.my-url.com

it should come like only www.my-url.com

Comment: This is how I have clicked that,                                                                                                                     **@if(strpos($exam->link, "http") != false)
               <p>Link : <a href="{{ $exam->link }}" target="_blank">{{ $exam->link }}</a></p>
               @elseif(strpos($exam->link, "http") != true)
               <p>Link : <a href="{{ "http://".$exam->link }}" target="_blank">{{ $exam->link }}</a></p>
               @endif**

Comment: Show the code as text with formatting. What does calling a url mean? Edit your question to provide clarification.

Comment: I guess you should write: `http://{{ $exam->link }}`

Answer (score 0):

You should add http or https while storing into DB as link is coming from DB directly.